# Fetching data from different table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fetch data from separate tables in sqlserver and display them together in GridView, Is that possible? if so then please suggest.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Sample SQL is :

SELECT * FROM firstTable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM secondTable

Then you can get the results to datatable and bind that datatable to gridview.

Comment: okay thanks ...now like if i want to show the fetched data in a format i want(vertical, editing the font size,color etc i.e styles), maybe without gridview.

Comment: You can use Table component or it is still possible to style your gridview as per your requirement. You can also create a custom component but in your case I think gridview or table component will do the work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, if both the returned result schemas are the same.

You would have to either join them at SQL level (with `UNION`) or at code level (with `Enumerable.Union()`).

Bottom line, you can only assign a single datasource to a control.

Comment: okay thanks ...now like if i want to show the  fetched data in a format i want(vertical, editing the font size,color etc i.e styles), maybe without gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I can think in two ways of do it, the first is that the SQL query join the data in the desired way and return it merged.

The other is making a query that returns a DataSet with the 2 tables and merge in c# creating a third datatable via code with the columns we want and populating later from the obtained data.

I will use the first option if is posible..

Comment: okay thanks ...now like if i want to show the  fetched data in a format i want(vertical, editing the font size,color etc i.e styles), maybe without gridview.